# how can I use R Studio data in shinyServer

Tags: shiny

In my local machine I use RStudio + Shiny to work properly.

Now that I have Shiny-Server installed on linux, but I do not know the Data generated by RStudiom.

how can I get Shiny-Server to read it?

Do not know what keyword query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Importing data in the server

As I see it, there are two ways to supply data in this situation.

The first one is to upload the data to the server where your shiny-apps are hosted. This can be done via `ssh` (`wget`) or something like `FileZilla`. You can put your data in the same folder as the app and then access them with relative paths. For example if you have

```
- app-folder
  - app.R
  - data.rds
  - more_data.csv
```

You can use `readRDS("data.rds")` or `readr::read_csv2("more_data.csv")` in `app.R` to use the data in the app.

The second option is to use `fileInput` inside your app. This will give you the option to upload data from your local machine in the GUI. This data will then be put onto the server temporarilly. See `?shiny::fileInput`.

### Exporting data from RStudio

There are numerous ways to do this. You can use `save` to write your whole workspace to disk. If you just want to save single objects, `saveRDS` is quite handy. If you want to save datasets (for example `data.frame`s) you can also use `readr::write_csv` or similar functions.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the way
Use RData to complete